# XSLT transformation at command line (using Saxon prepackaged with Oxygen)

Tags: xml, xslt, command-line, saxon, tei

I am using command line on Mac OS X (10.11.5) to try transformations outside of Oxygen using Saxon (as I get ready to do bulk processing of large sets of XML-TEI files to HTML).

I use the following basic command:

```
java -cp /Applications/Oxygen XML Editor/lib/saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform  -s:/Users/idjet/Desktop/test/sourcefilename.xml -xsl:/Users/idjet/Desktop/test/transformfilename.xsl -o:/Users/idjet/Desktop/test/testoutput.html
```

But it produces this error that I can't get to the bottom of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: XML
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XML
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Thanks in advance.

(I admit I'm unfamiliar with Java.)

Comment: I think when there is path contain spaces, you need to be capture in between quot

Comment: @Rupesh ah, of course. I forgot to backslash the empty spaces. Now it works. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the version of the Saxon JAR file that's distributed with oXygen is not designed to be used outside oXygen. To run Saxon from the command line, first download a free-standing version of Saxon (from SourceForge in the case of Saxon-HE, or from saxonica.com in the case of commercial editions).

In particular, oXygen enables features such as Streaming and Schema-Awareness in Saxon, and to use these features outside the oXygen environment you will need a license key from Saxonica.

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay. I did notice the command line response that it was searching for licensing before processing. Will I face any conflicts if I download the free-standing version (to a non-Oxygen directory)?

Comment: You may get conflicts if you have both JARs on the same classpath, but not otherwise.